# Filtered RSS Feed via Push Notifications on iPhone

Tags: iphone, rss

It's a bit tricky but I'm looking for an app that filters RSS Feeds by keywords and redirects links to Safari. My filtered feeds should be notified in a menu like this and, when tapped, should be opened in Safari.. Does exist something like this?

[image]

Comment: What source for RSS do you use? CNN, Google, ect...

Comment: I basically take RSS links from websites.. Most of them use feedburner

Comment: you can use add ons for browsers for RSS feeders, so no need to push notification

Comment: Do exist addons for iOS' Safari?!

Comment: do exist in iOS 8 !

Comment: "Safari also picked up the ability to add RSS feeds to your Shared Links feed. To add a new RSS feed just visit the website in Safari, open up your shared links, go to Subscriptions and tap “Add Current Site.”" I found this feature of iOS 8.. I hope that some developer will use this new feature to develope an addon.. I can't find a place with addons for iOS 8 :v Any help?